# OpenlayerMap Vue3 points with names

Tags: vuejs3

Im trying to add name of point on openlayermap in vue3. Names of point are display but all points have same title.

```
      <ol-animated-clusterlayer :animationDuration="500" :distance="40" title="CLUSTER"
        preview="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MelihAltintas/vue3-openlayers/main/src/assets/cluster.png">
        <ol-source-vector ref="vectorsource">
          <ol-feature v-for="index in mapCover" :key="index">
            <ol-geom-point :coordinates="[
             index.lon, index.lat
            ]"></ol-geom-point>
          </ol-feature>
        </ol-source-vector>

        <ol-style :overrideStyleFunction="overrideStyleFunction">
          <ol-style-stroke color="red" :width="2"></ol-style-stroke>
          <ol-style-fill color="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"></ol-style-fill>

          <ol-style-circle :radius="20">
            <ol-style-stroke color="black" :width="15" :lineDash="[]" lineCap="butt"></ol-style-stroke>
            <ol-style-fill color="black"></ol-style-fill>
          </ol-style-circle>

          <ol-style-text>
            <ol-style-fill color="white"></ol-style-fill>
          </ol-style-text>
        </ol-style>
      </ol-animated-clusterlayer>

      <ol-overlay  v-for="(point, index) in mapCover" :key="index" :position="selectedCityPosition" v-if="selectedCityName != '' && !drawEnable">
        <template v-slot="slotProps">
          <div class="overlay-content">
            {{ point.name }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </ol-overlay>
```

How to add name to point ?